# What if I forgot to remove 'debugger;' in a .js file & deploy it on live. Will it affect my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on a nodeJs application & by mistake I forgot to remove the debugger; code in it. Will I face any issues if I deploy the same code on live ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debugger` statements will affect Node application only if debugging mode was enabled, with `--inspect` option or other ways listed in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/). Otherwise they will be ignored; their performance impact is minimal.

A possible way to avoid this situation in future is to enable ESLint [`no-debugger` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-debugger) and enforce it on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem.
Also in future you can use some tools to automatically exclude `debugger` instruction from your production code.
E.g. with [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-debugger).